# See log in cmd line after svn update to revision

Tags: svn, command-line, revision, svn-update

If I update to an older revision:

```
svn update -rXXXX
```

and then try to list the log:

```
svn log
```

I only see entries up to the revision `XXXX`. How can I see the newer ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn log` will use the working copy's revision if it isn't specified.  From the help text:

```
log: Show the log messages for a set of revision(s) and/or path(s).
usage: 1. log [PATH][@REV]
       2. log URL[@REV] [PATH...]

  1. Print the log messages for the URL corresponding to PATH
     (default: '.'). If specified, REV is the revision in which the
     URL is first looked up, and the default revision range is REV:1.
     If REV is not specified, the default revision range is BASE:1,
     since the URL might not exist in the HEAD revision.
```

Note the last sentence and that "BASE" is defined as "base rev of item's working copy" (again from the help text).  So, just pass "HEAD" as the revision you want a log from:

```
svn log -r HEAD:1
```

Comment: This shows me only one latest entry, not all/more of them.

Comment: Sorry, left off the `:1` part.